# Search Items in QJsonArray

Tags: c++, json, qt, stl

I have the following JsonArray and want to search for a value by its "ID".
Here the JSON which is stored in the QJsonArray:

```
{
   "datasources":[
   {"id":1, "name":"tps-pos",       "display-name":"TPS Position"},
   {"id":2, "name":"tps-timer",     "display-name":"TPS Timer"},
   {"id":3, "name":"laterial-g",    "display-name":"Lateral G"},
   {"id":4, "name":"longitudal-g",  "display-name":"Longitudal G"},
   {"id":5, "name":"Z",             "display-name":"Z"},
   {"id":6, "name":"afr",           "display-name":"AFR"},
   {"id":135, "name":"IAT",         "display-name":"Intake Air temperature"},
   {"id":179, "name":"RPM",         "display-name":"RPM"}
]}
```

I tried `std::find` for it, where `m_list` contains the id that should be found in the JSON.

```
auto result = std::find(m_DataSourceArray.begin(),m_DataSourceArray.end(), m_list[0]);
```

When debugging, I see that "result" is always the same as `m_DataSourceArray` + the field iterator: (debugger view:)

```
result  @0x7ed9e0   QJsonArray::iterator
    a   <8 Elemente>    QJsonArray
        [0] <3 Elemente>    QJsonValue (Object)
        [1] <3 Elemente>    QJsonValue (Object)
        [2] <3 Elemente>    QJsonValue (Object)
        [3] <3 Elemente>    QJsonValue (Object)
        [4] <3 Elemente>    QJsonValue (Object)
        [5] <3 Elemente>    QJsonValue (Object)
        [6] <3 Elemente>    QJsonValue (Object)
        [7] <3 Elemente>    QJsonValue (Object)
    i   8   int
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd create a new function for searching. Like:

```
QJsonObject findValueFromJsonArray(QJsonArray arr, QString key, int val) {
    for (const auto obj : arr) {
        if (obj.toObject().value(key) == val)
            return obj.toObject();
    }
    return QJsonObject();
}
```

Now I can search for a value by id.

```
    QJsonArray m_DataSourceArray = m_DataSourceObject.value(QString("datasources")).toArray();

    QJsonObject obj = findValueFromJsonArray(m_DataSourceArray, "id", 10);
    // Array doesn't contain a value with id 10
    if (obj.isEmpty())
        qDebug() << "Empty QJsonObject";

    QJsonObject obj2 = findValueFromJsonArray(m_DataSourceArray, "id", 2);
    if (!obj2.isEmpty())
        qDebug() << "Not empty!";

    qDebug() << obj2;
    qDebug() << "Display-name of obj2: " << obj2.value("display-name").toString();
    qDebug() << findValueFromJsonArray(m_DataSourceArray, "id", 4);
```

Outputs:

```
Empty QJsonObject
Not empty!
QJsonObject({"display-name":"TPS Timer","id":2,"name":"tps-timer"})
Display-name of obj2:  "TPS Timer"
QJsonObject({"display-name":"Longitudal G","id":4,"name":"longitudal-g"})
```

Of course you wouldn't need to create a new function to do the search if you don't need to do searching elsewhere.

If you would need to find a value by name or display-name, you can create a second function. Note how the val parameter is now QString type instead of int.

```
QJsonObject findValueFromJsonArray(QJsonArray arr, QString key, QString val) {
    for (const auto obj : arr) {
        if (obj.toObject().value(key).toString().contains(val, Qt::CaseSensitivity::CaseInsensitive))
            return obj.toObject();
    }
    return QJsonObject();
}
```

Now I am able to search for a value by its id or name:

```
    QJsonArray m_DataSourceArray = m_DataSourceObject.value(QString("datasources")).toArray();

    QJsonObject obj = findValueFromJsonArray(m_DataSourceArray, "name", "foo");
    // Array doesn't contain a value with name 'foo'
    if (obj.isEmpty())
        qDebug() << "Empty QJsonObject";

    QJsonObject obj2 = findValueFromJsonArray(m_DataSourceArray, "name", "tps-pos");
    if (!obj2.isEmpty())
        qDebug() << "Not empty!";

    qDebug() << obj2;
    qDebug() << "Display-name of obj2: " << obj2.value("display-name").toString();
    qDebug() << findValueFromJsonArray(m_DataSourceArray, "id", 4);
    qDebug() << findValueFromJsonArray(m_DataSourceArray, "name", "z");
    qDebug() << findValueFromJsonArray(m_DataSourceArray, "display-name", "rpm");
```

Outputs:

```
Empty QJsonObject
Not empty!
QJsonObject({"display-name":"TPS Position","id":1,"name":"tps-pos"})
Display-name of obj2:  "TPS Position"
QJsonObject({"display-name":"Longitudal G","id":4,"name":"longitudal-g"})
QJsonObject({"display-name":"Z","id":5,"name":"Z"})
QJsonObject({"display-name":"RPM","id":179,"name":"RPM"})
```